# Create label as group by every 8 rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a column ```label`` that shows the index,every index will have eight rows.

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(value=runif(101, 1, 99),col1=sample(LETTERS, 101, TRUE),col2=sample(LETTERS, 101, TRUE))
```

The result wanted is shown below:

```
 value col1 col2 label
1  56.861251    G    M   1
2   5.570896    S    B   1
3  40.102606    X    R   1
4  57.246643    L    W   1
5  67.547549    N    K   1
6  66.788666    C    P   1
7  35.856123    S    A   1
8  94.287007    I    W   1
9  35.365653    E    P   2
10 28.818185    J    A   2
11 49.898110    Q    I   2
12 68.769551    B    N   2
13 28.002404    U    C   2
14 28.205527    R    B   2
15 35.699103    Y    D   2
16 84.576121    V    C   2
17 45.888039    U    T   3
18 47.611576    N    G   3
.
.
.
```

Comment: with base R: `df$label = ceiling(1:nrow(df)/8)`

Comment: You tagged [tag:data.table] but used `data.frame`, suggesting you aren't really using the `data.table` package. But if you were, I_O's suggestion is still trivially applied there: `df[, label := ceiling(seq_len(.N)/8)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, label = ceiling(n()/8)))
```

Or in base R, as @I_O has commented:

```r
df$label = ceiling(1:nrow(df)/8)
```